# Ubuntu Snappy Core 16.04 RPi3 - questions

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have couple of questions regarding Snappy Core 16.04. I have been playing around with it for a while and have couple of concearns:

1. How to use network-manager ? There is a snap provided by canonical called network-manager but when using nmcli it does not work.
2. Readonly file system: Iw ould like to enter my wlan SSID and password in interfaces but the file system is write-protected how to deal with it (in general - i eman editing linux config etc)

Regards

Comment: As snappy is something new and they build it up "completely from the ground", we should expect alot to work differently.

About your questions:

ad 1. the command would be `network-manager.nmcli`  
ad 2. the command might be `wireless-tools.iw`

plus I once by accident stumbled over some plans by "them" to use netplan for managing your network devices and then passing them on to all the kind of handlers like network-manager.

Comment: see my tutorial at http://askubuntu.com/questions/585790/how-to-connect-wifi-network-from-raspberry-pi-2-snappy/886737#886737 and see if you can configure your wifi that way

Answer (score 1):

I got my wifi setup working using network-manager. In essence:

```
# Install Network Manager using Snap
sudo snap install network-manager

# Turn on the WiFi interface
network-manager.nmcli r wifi on

# verify the WiFi is on
network-manager.nmcli r

# List the available network
network-manager.nmcli d wifi list

# Connect to a network
network-manager.nmcli d wifi connect <ssid> password <password>

# verify it is connected to WiFi
network-manager.nmcli c
```

That should be it. I put it together in [gist](https://gist.github.com/cyan198/6ecdb86267498a51587b4337e47e10f6).